# Regex between 1 and 12 doesn't work on form validation

Tags: regex, forms, symfony

I'm creating a form in symfony2 and one field looks like this:

```
->add('periodicity', 'number', array(
                'required'    => true,
                'attr'        => array(
                    'autocomplete' => 'off',
                    'placeholder' => '2',
                ),
                'label'       => 'periodicity*',
                'trim'        => true,
                'constraints' => array(
                    new Constraints\NotBlank(),
                    new Assert\Regex(array(
                        'pattern' => "/^[1-9]|1[0-2]$/",
                        'match'   => true,
                        'message' => "Tapez des chiffres entre 1 et 12" )),
                )
            ))
```

In the validation of the form when I put a number superior than 12 I don't get any errors.

Comment: I know you have an answer to this but the `Range` constraint would probably work better for this use case. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put them inside a group.

```
^([1-9]|1[0-2])$
```